# Issue on drop-down "? string:2 ?" list in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using AngularJs ng-model for selecting the drop-down value
And i am using `datatable` for sorting the column.

```
 <select id="{{user.id}}" ng-model="user.commit" name="options" ng-change="update_commit_level(account.commit , user ,oldValue)" ng-init="oldValue = account.commit">
                        <option value="1">Commit1</option>
                        <option value="2">Commit2</option>
                        <option value="3">Commit3</option>
                      </select>
```

**> In browser inspecting element I am getting this :**

[image]
? string:2 ?

I tried this way also but not working ...

```
ng-init = "account.commit = '2'"
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please be more clear , what error or what output you are looking for ??

Comment: You need init your `ng-model` `user.commit`. In controller code try this `user.commit = "2"`.

Comment: I did but i did't get selected value in drop-down list

Answer (score 2):

The issue is related to plugin when you are using `datatable` plugin after so if you nee both stuff just use Angular `<select>` tag in angularJs way using `ng-options`

```
<table datatable="ng" class="table">
```

**So the solution is here using ng-options**

```
<select id="{{account.id}}" ng-model="account.commit" ng-options="item.ID as item.Title for item in items" ng-change="update_commit_level(account.commit , account)"></select>

$scope.items = [
      {ID: '', Title: '----Select----'},
      {ID: '1', Title: 'Commit1'},
      {ID: '2', Title: 'Commit2'},
      {ID: '3', Title: 'Commit3'},
    ];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try selected command in option

```
     <select id="{{user.id}}" ng-model="user.commit" name="options" ng-change="update_commit_level(account.commit , user ,oldValue)" ng-init="oldValue = account.commit">
                        <option value="1">Commit1</option>
                        <option value="2" selected>Commit2</option>
                        <option value="3">Commit3</option>
                      </select>
```

Comment: Yes this is good way I did it but when you are using datatable plugin in angularjs then it is stop working.

Comment: Yes this is only Html part